# MySql - PHP UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

with this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("
 UPDATE skroutz SET 
 Image_Link=(
   SELECT file_url 
   FROM bonnie_virtuemart_medias 
   INNER JOIN bonnie_virtuemart_product_medias 
   ON bonnie_virtuemart_medias. virtuemart_media_id =bonnie_virtuemart_product_medias. virtuemart_media_id 
   WHERE virtuemart_product_id=Unique_ID LIMIT 1)",$db);
```

I get a path of the form
/images/stories/virtuemart/product/1200x1000.gif

Get it from table in my database that already exists and the transfer to another table with UPDATE

Trying to add a static string in front of the name but I can not.
Specifically, I want the new table to convey stored as:

http://www.example.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/1200x1000.gif

That adds to data in front the: www.example.com

Can someone help?

What I tried without success:

```
$result = mysql_query("
  UPDATE skroutz 
  SET Image_Link=('www.example.com'
  SELECT file_url 
  FROM bonnie_virtuemart_medias 
  INNER JOIN bonnie_virtuemart_product_medias 
  ON bonnie_virtuemart_medias. virtuemart_media_id =bonnie_virtuemart_product_medias. virtuemart_media_id 
  WHERE virtuemart_product_id=Unique_ID LIMIT 1)",$db);
```

Comment: Look into the [Concat function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the CONCAT function:

```
$result = mysql_query("
  UPDATE skroutz 
  SET Image_Link=(
  SELECT CONCAT('www.example.com', file_url)
  FROM bonnie_virtuemart_medias 
  INNER JOIN bonnie_virtuemart_product_medias 
  ON bonnie_virtuemart_medias. virtuemart_media_id = bonnie_virtuemart_product_medias. virtuemart_media_id 
  WHERE virtuemart_product_id=Unique_ID LIMIT 1)",$db);
```

Comment: Glad it works, but the comment above is right -- you should absolutely not use mysql_query. I missed that when answering.

Answer (score 0):

Since I made update of your question it is obviously that you are trying something strange.

If I got your goal correctly you can try something like:

`SET Image_Link=CONCAT('www.example.com',(
  SELECT file_url 
  ...
  ))",$db);`